# Angularjs $stateChangeStart check if string is in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code inside my `app.run()`:

```
window.audienceConfig = InstitutionConfiguration.checkConfiguration(INSTITUTION_URL).then( response => {
    window.audienceConfig = response.institution.landing_configuration;
    console.log(window.audienceConfig);
});
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {...}
```

Inside my `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart')` I want to check if my `toState.name` is equal to any of the `window.audience.Config.somePage.routerName` The `console.log()` of `window.audienceConfig` outputs the following:

```
"dashboard": {
    "routerName": "basicLayout.dashboard",
    "audience": [
        "faculty",
        "student",
        "employee"
    ]
},
"profile": {
    "routerName": "basicLayout.content",
    "audience": [
        "faculty",
        "student"
    ]
},
"academic_resources": {
    "routerName": "basicLayout.academicResources",
    "audience": [
        "student"
    ]
},
"university_services": {
    "routerName": "basicLayout.universityServices",
    "audience": [
        "student"
    ]
},
"support_center": {
    "routerName": "basicLayout.supportCenter",
    "audience": [
        "student",
        "faculty",
        "employee"
    ]
},
"progress_coach": {
    "routerName": "basicLayout.progressCoach",
    "audience": [
        "student"
    ]
}
```

I need to verify if every time I change route, `toState.name` is equal to any of the `routerName` properties of the object above, is there a way to do this inside an if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually know two ways of doing so:

The **first one** , I´ve seen many people who don´t like it, but it consists on checking if the name of your state exists on your state. Add it within `$stateChangeStart` event function ;you achieve it with the following piece of code. For example if you want to check if you are going to dashboard.

```
if (toState.name.indexOf('dashboard') > -1  ) {
            //do something. 
        }
```

The **second way** to achieve it is by using the native $state which I think belongs to **ui-router, in case you are using that library**, or any you are using for changing the states.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {...
  var stateName = $state.name; 
  console.log(stateName)
  console.log(toState)
 //Check your console because stateName and toState are formated as an 
  //object or smth like that.
 //You need to read and extract the first element of the array with a 
 //foreach. After that, you may use the real name from the state and compare
if (stateNameExtracted  === toStateExtracted){
     //do Something
    }
}
```

The second approach requires more logic, but in my opinion, it´s cleaner.